# Using one user database to authenticate users in 2 different cloud based (aws/gcp) and only once

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

So this is the case:

**What we have:**

We have a Service (webApp) in kubernetes API + Vue.js frontend hosted in AWS.
And we also have some Services (webApp) in Kubernetes API + React.js frontend hosted in GCP.

We are able to use same domain subdomains for each (like: a.domain.com and b.domain.com).

**What we need:**

1. We need to let the user think this 2 servers are only one.
2. The idea is that the user uses the same Username/password for both servers, but
3. the most immportant part is that he only needs to log in to one of this to be logged in the other automaticaly.
4. We have the parent domain in Google, and we prefer a solution that is implemented in GCP and the AWS server should just consume this auth method/config/etc.

Love to hear some ideas

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple replicas of the webApp frontend distributed in multi-cloud environments, you can use dynamic DNS and load balancing services like Cloudflare provides to distribute the access to your app frontend as  [explained here.](https://medium.com/@gmusumeci/how-to-build-step-by-step-a-multi-cloud-website-running-on-aws-azure-and-google-cloud-with-39dc98436891)

Then you need connect the multi-cloud VPCs and make accessible your backend to your multiple frontends.

You can use [managed VPN services](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/patterns-for-connecting-other-csps-with-gcp#managed_vpn_between_cloud_providers) from both cloud providers to have an encrypted channel between VPCs in both cloud environments and to transfer data by using private IP addresses.

Google offers [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/interop-guides) as a managed VPN service for encrypted IPsec tunnels, which can be used on the Google end. AWS offers AWS Site-to-Site VPN and Azure offers Azure VPN gateway. You can connect your VPCs between the environments by using one or multiple VPN tunnels.

With that you can operate your webApp on multi cloud.

Comment: The VPC intention is like a load balancer but with multicloud ? I think that is not what we are searching for, because the aws and the google web apps are different web apps in our case. The idea is that these apps are complementary and the same user uses both, and we want to give them the opportunity to use only 1 auth method for both apps and take advantage of both services/apps with only one account.